# How to pause during a callback using python 3.6?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, python-3.6

I am relatively new to python and I am programming a computer player for Othello. I am using the callback method to find the position of the mouse click on the board. I need to be able to pause halfway through the callback so that the player's move is shown followed by the computer's. However, for now, both moves happen together so the player cannot see the result of his/her move. When I tried the `time.sleep()` method it just delayed the execution of the whole callback. 
This is a simplified version of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.configure(background="black")
canvas=Canvas(root, bg = "black", height = 708, width = 1280)
def callback(event):
    if event.y < 350:
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,234,780,334,fill="#004800",width=0)
        time.sleep(2)
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,374,780,474,fill="#004800",width=0)
    else:
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,374,780,474,fill="#004800",width=0)
        time.sleep(2)
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,234,780,334,fill="#004800",width=0)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, pady=0, padx=0)      
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what actually is the motive behind the same? What do you intend to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both moves seem to happen simultaneously because the canvas content is updated only after `time.sleep` finishes. To see the first move separately, you need to force the canvas to update before the pause with `root.update_idletasks()`.

By the way, you don't have to import the module `time` to pause, you can use `root.after(2000)` (the time is in ms) instead.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.configure(background="black")
canvas = Canvas(root, bg = "black", height = 708, width = 1280)

def callback(event):
    if event.y < 350:
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,234,780,334,fill="red",width=0)
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.after(2000)
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,374,780,474,fill="#004800",width=0)
    else:
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,374,780,474,fill="red",width=0)
        root.update_idletasks()
        root.after(2000)
        canvas.create_rectangle(500,234,780,334,fill="#004800",width=0)

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, pady=0, padx=0)      
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would add that you cannot use sleep inside a tkinter instance as it freezes the mainloop.

Comment: @Mkike Yes but I think this is not a big problem here since the OP probably doesn't want the player to be able to do anything in the GUI while the moves are displayed.

Comment: There are other more appropriate ways to prevent the user from doing things. `sleep()` causes issues and can be code breaking as the code grows. `sleep()` and tkinter just don't work together at all.